# Jekyll posts filenames without dates

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I don't care about dates because I edit my previous posts all the time, so I would like to replace `_posts/2015-05-05-something.md` by `_posts/something.md`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pages doesn't require files to have dates, eg: `_posts/2015-05-05-something.md` becomes `something.md`.

(The answer came from the amazing Github support)

Answer (score 0):

To do it you need to edit `_config.yml` file. Variable you are interested in is `permalink`. Jekyll has 4 build-in styles:

```
date - /:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title.html
pretty - /:categories/:year/:month/:day/:title/
ordinal - /:categories/:year/:y_day/:title.html
none - /:categories/:title.html
```

You probably need to use `none`. Or you can build your own with a simple templates: more info [here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/).

Comment: I meant the file names themselves (not the URLs)